# Export-Csv Exporting List Properties Instead of Content

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to export a list to a CSV file. The output *should* look something like this:

| Computer Name | BIOS | Operating System | Version | Disk Number | Size (GB) | Partition Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEVICE1 | UEFI | Microsoft Windows 10 Pro | 10.0.19042.0 | 0 | 954 | GPT |
| DEVICE1 | UEFI | Microsoft Windows 10 Pro | 10.0.19042.0 | 1 | 119 | GPT |
| etc... |  |  |  |  |  |  |

However, the output in the CSV file looks like this:

| Count | Length | LongLength | Rank | SyncRoot | IsReadOnly | IsFixedSize | IsSynchronized |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | System.Object[] | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |

**Relevant Code**

```
$Result = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

#Irrelevant Code...
foreach($Device in $Devices){
#More irrelevant code...

Write-Host "`tCompiling device information... " -NoNewline
try{
    $Cmd = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock{
        Get-Disk | Foreach-Object{
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                "Computer Name"    = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                "BIOS"             = if (Test-Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\control\SecureBoot\State) {"UEFI"} else {"Legacy"}
                "Operating System" = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption
                "Version"          = [Environment]::OSVersion | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version
                "Disk Number"      = $_.number
                "Size (GB)"        = [int]($_.size/1GB)
                "Partition Type"   = $_.PartitionStyle
            }
        }
    
    }
    $Cmd = $Cmd | Select * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, RunspaceId 
    $Result.Add($Cmd)
    Write-Host "Success" -ForegroundColor Green
}catch{
    Write-Host "Failed" -ForegroundColor Red
    $Result.Add(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Computer Name"    = $Device
            "BIOS"             = $QueryErrorMsg
            "Operating System" = $QueryErrorMsg
            "Version"          = $QueryErrorMsg
            "Disk Number"      = $QueryErrorMsg
            "Size (GB)"        = $QueryErrorMsg
            "Partition Type"   = $QueryErrorMsg
        }
    )
    Continue
}finally{
    Remove-PSSession $Session
    Write-Host "`tConnection terminated."
}
$Count++
}

if($DisplayResults){
    $Result | ft -a
}

if($ExportToCsv){
    $Result | Export-Csv -Path ($OutputDirectory + "\DiskPartitionAudit $((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss tt')).csv") -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Any ideas how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Why `$Cmd = $Cmd | Select * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, RunspaceId` if you already defined your own **PS*Custom*Object** properties?

Comment: If I didn't include that there, rather than when exporting or displaying `$Result`, then those properties were included in my output. The accepted answer solved this for me.

Comment: @iRon because Invoke-Command adds those for you.. you know, for your convenience. I've always hated that. Even the -HideComputerName you can still end up with a psscomputername property!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you are adding all your collected records in `$cmd` as a single object to `$result`. Instead, use `AddRange()`. I also changed the select-object as I was getting PSComputerName and PSShowComputerName in my csvs

```
$Result = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

#Irrelevant Code...
foreach($Device in $Devices){
#More irrelevant code...

Write-Host "`tCompiling device information... " -NoNewline
try{
    $Cmd = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock{
        Get-Disk | Foreach-Object{
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                "Computer Name"    = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                "BIOS"             = if (Test-Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\control\SecureBoot\State) {"UEFI"} else {"Legacy"}
                "Operating System" = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption
                "Version"          = [Environment]::OSVersion | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version
                "Disk Number"      = $_.number
                "Size (GB)"        = [int]($_.size/1GB)
                "Partition Type"   = $_.PartitionStyle
            }
        }
    } -HideComputerName 

    $Result.AddRange($Cmd)

    Write-Host "Success" -ForegroundColor Green
}catch{
    Write-Host "Failed" -ForegroundColor Red
    $Result.Add(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Computer Name"    = $Device
            "BIOS"             = $QueryErrorMsg
            "Operating System" = $QueryErrorMsg
            "Version"          = $QueryErrorMsg
            "Disk Number"      = $QueryErrorMsg
            "Size (GB)"        = $QueryErrorMsg
            "Partition Type"   = $QueryErrorMsg
        }
    )
    Continue
}finally{
    Remove-PSSession $Session
    Write-Host "`tConnection terminated."
}
$Count++
}

if($DisplayResults){
    $Result | ft -a
}

if($ExportToCsv){
    $Result | Select * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceId,PSComputerName,PSShowComputerName |
        Export-Csv -Path ($OutputDirectory + "\DiskPartitionAudit $((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss tt')).csv") -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Haven't run into this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "Select-Object" with the list of attributes:

`$Result | Select-Object -Property "Computer Name", "BIOS", "Operating System", "Version", "Disk Number", "Size (GB)", "Partition Type" | Export-Csv -Path ($OutputDirectory + "\DiskPartitionAudit $((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss tt')).csv") -NoTypeInformation`